# How do I remove 'p' tags with querySelector

Tags: javascript

I'm using querySelector to remove 'p' tags that have my in them; the last three in the HTML; but with the code I wrote it's not working

//html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>

</head> 

<body>

I have an <h1>This is my todo list</h1> 

// with five <p> tags

<p>I have to study databases </P>
<p>I have to study jquery</P>
<p> I have to continue my workouts</P>
<p>I have to receive my degree </P>
<p>I have to thank my instructors</P>

<script src="note.js"></script>

</body

</html>
```

//JavaScript

```
const paragraphs = document.querySelector('p')

paragraphs.forEach(function(paragraph){

    if(paragraph.textContent.includes('my')) {

           paragraph.remove()

  }

})
```

I want the last three `<p>` tags removed from the browser but nothing happens; I've tried it with the browser console also

// Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

[`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns first matched element. Since it does not return *NodeList*, the result does not have `forEach()`. To target all the elements you have to use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

> The Document method [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a static (not live) *NodeList* representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

Change

```
const paragraphs = document.querySelector('p')
```

To

```
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p')
```

```js
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p')
paragraphs.forEach(function(paragraph){
  if(paragraph.textContent.includes('my')) {
    paragraph.remove()
  }
});
```

```html
<p>I have to study databases </p>
<p>I have to study jquery</p>
<p> I have to continue my workouts</p>
<p>I have to receive my degree </p>
<p>I have to thank my instructors</p>
```

**Please Note:** Though it works, you should not use capital `P` to close the tag.